# connect to localhost using solana web3.js

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

I'm building a miniature next react app (for test purpose) to test a js script that i made, that is supposed to mint NFT on my account. I'm following [this](https://spl.solana.com/token#example-create-a-non-fungible-token) to makes everything works.
But, when i try any of these two:

```
  const connection = new Connection(
    clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
  );

  const connection = new Connection(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8899",
  );
```

then i get an error in createMint function:

```
  let mint = await createMint(
    connection,
    mintRequester,           // payer
    mintRequester.publicKey, // mint
    null,                    // freeze
    0,
  );
```

the error is:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: unexpected type, use Uint8Array
Source

scripts/mint.ts (48:4) @ async*_callee$

  46 | 
  47 |   let mint = await createMint(
> 48 |     connection,
     |    ^
  49 |     mintRequester,           // payer
  50 |     mintRequester.publicKey, // mint
  51 |     null,                    // freeze
```

note: `testnet` timeout, cant use it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run `solana-test-validator` when using localhost.